# RxSwift: upgrade model state when textfield gets focus

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have a `UIViewController` with 3 `UITextField`s. Every time either of the fields gets focus, I want to set a new text value for a tip label above. What is the best way to achieve this with `RxSwift`?

Comment: To clarify, it doesn't matter which field received the focus?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This does what you're looking for.  Any time a `UITextField` would send a `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` delegate message, you instead get an `Observable` for that.  Then you map that `Observable` into the correct string for that text field.  Then combine all 3 of those Observables into just one, where the latest event is from the text field that most recently called that delegate message.  Then you bind that value to the tooltip's text.

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    @IBOutlet weak var tooltip: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField3: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let textField1Text = textField1.rx_controlEvent(.EditingDidBegin)
            .map { "text field 1 message" }

        let textField2Text = textField2.rx_controlEvent(.EditingDidBegin)
            .map { "text field 2 message" }

        let textField3Text = textField3.rx_controlEvent(.EditingDidBegin)
            .map { "text field 3 message" }

        Observable.of(textField1Text, textField2Text, textField3Text).merge()
            .bindTo(tooltip.rx_text)
            .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, @solidcell! that's exactly I've been looking for!